# C# Windows Form_Closing Issue

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I seem to be having difficult in having a Dialog box pop up and function properly when a use clicks the red "X" button in the top right corner of the application. I can make the Dialog appear to ask if they really want to close the application, but regardless of what they click, it will close the form. The code I have is as follows;

```
            private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to close?", "Close Program", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried instead of e.Cancel to check if dr is equal to ok but the same situation happens.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `e.Cancel = true;` cancels the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.Cancel = true;` cancels the action. and it is by default `false`. you are not setting it to true anywhere. try this.

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to close?", "Close Program", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

oneliner:

```
e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to close?", "Close Program", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Comment: ok i made it work it isnt dr != DialogResult.Cancel but dr == DialogResult. Thank you for the help

Comment: one more question for you. I have a button in a menu strip that also closes the form, but the problem is, i have it set to the same kind of code. after i click ok, it will run the form_closing code as well so I have a double dialog box happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: just call `Close();` from the menu strip button (dont use additional check there). it will trigger the form closing and the `Main_FormClosing` will run

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are never setting `e.Cancel` to `true`.  I would modify your message box to show Yes and No buttons as I feel it makes it clearer to the user and then I would just set `e.Cancel` to true if the user chooses No.

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to close?", "Close Program", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    e.Cancel = dr == DialogResult.No;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Closing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are released and the form is disposed. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. **To cancel the closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.**

**e.Cancel = true;**